# loops in r only giving final value

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to build a loop which goes through all values of my i and prints them in a matrix. instead I'm only getting the final answer, could you please advise where I'm going wrong:

```
mat2 <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
for(i in 1:10){
  M <- 5000*i
  insurer[i] <- simdata[simdata<=M]
  reinsurer[i] <- simdata[simdata>M]
  mat2[1,] <- mean(insurer)
  mat2[2,] <- mean(reinsurer)
  mat2[3,] <- var(insurer)
  mat2[4,] <- var(reinsurer)
  mat2
}
```

output is as follows:

```
mat2
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]
[1,]      9694.34      9694.34      9694.34      9694.34      9694.34      9694.34
[2,]     60776.64     60776.64     60776.64     60776.64     60776.64     60776.64
[3,]  82806727.19  82806727.19  82806727.19  82806727.19  82806727.19  82806727.19
[4,] 103927604.88 103927604.88 103927604.88 103927604.88 103927604.88 103927604.88
             [,7]         [,8]         [,9]        [,10]
[1,]      9694.34      9694.34      9694.34      9694.34
[2,]     60776.64     60776.64     60776.64     60776.64
[3,]  82806727.19  82806727.19  82806727.19  82806727.19
[4,] 103927604.88 103927604.88 103927604.88 103927604.88
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Are you looking for 10 different matrix objects? Or a list consisting of 10 matrices? In this case you are writing over the pre-existing matrix with each loop iteration.

Comment: Try adding `print(mat2)` to just show for each interaction if you want all matrices in a single object you need to change your code.

Comment: I added an i for the column reference and it worked, thanks for your help